# Is there a function to split by the FIRST instance of a delimiter in C?

Tags: c, split, delimiter, strtok

I understand that the `strtok()` function allows you to split a string with a predefined delimiter (or a set of delimiters), but is there a way to split a string by the FIRST INSTANCE of a delimiter?

Example: (Delimiter=":")

Input: "Host: localhost:5000"

Output: ["Host", "localhost:5000"]

The output does not necessarily need to be in a list, but the string needs to be split into two strings.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: use strchr to locate the delimiter, place a 0 at the location (so now you get the first string) and the strcpy the rest  for the second string. Or you could just call strtok once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you call `strtok`, use the delimiter you want to split with.

For the second call, use an empty delimiter string (if you really want the rest of the string) or use `"\n"`, in the case that your string might include a newline character and you don't want that in the split (or even `"\r\n"`):

```c
    const char* first = strtok(buf, ":");
    const char* rest = strtok(NULL, "");
 /* or:     const char* rest = strtok(NULL, "\n"); */
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can easily accomplish this task by using the [string](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) class and its members [find](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and [substr](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

I coded a small snippet to demostrate it:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    string sInput = "Host:localhost:5000";
    string sSeparator = ":";
    string s1, s2;

    size_t pos = sInput.find(sSeparator);
    s1 = sInput.substr(0, pos);
    s2 = sInput.substr(pos +1, string::npos);

    // Print result strings
    printf(s1.c_str());
    printf("\n");
    printf(s2.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, the project requires me to use C, not C++.